# Command Button timeout parameter: maximum value

Tags: visualforce, timeout, commandbutton

I am using a `apex:commandButton` with a `timeout` parameter. What maximum value can i use for the `timeout`? In the doc there is no clear description about that:

> The amount of time (in milliseconds) before an AJAX update request
>   should time out.

I've tried values from 1000 to 90000. Seems to work fine. But now i want to increase this value to 5 minutes for example. Is it possible? Where can i found official infos about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any information over and above the line that you have found in the developer docs.

Typically frameworks don't place an upper limit on Ajax request timeouts - effectively what you are doing is telling the browser that even if the request completes after the timeout, its results will be ignored. It really comes down to the maximum length of time that your server side processing can take, how many concurrent Ajax requests you are making and what the user experience is - if it is a blocking Ajax call, for example, you probably wouldn't want a large timeout.

Comment: Thanks Bob. In my case the command button executes an SOQL search query and it is limited to the 120 seconds, so i think this will make no sense to make the timeoute more than 120000.